# Custom Views for Case Records in Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I have a Case View which shows all the records that were created by the me (My Cases view). I now want to all those Cases edited/modified by me to be visible in that view. The problem is those modified by me could be later modified by the system when a workflow updates the Case, which changes the Modified By User data. Thus, not allowing me to use Modified By (Current User) as a condition for the view.

Is there any other way or condition which I can use to make sure the I can accomplish this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a new Entity with One to Many relationship with Case Entity. Whenever there is Insert or Update you can add a new record in the mapping entity with Modified By Information and Created On OOB.

You can create a view in the new entity with record modified by Me.

P.S - Single case record will be edited multiple times with multiple users so it will result in high volume of data and may want to look for archiving strategy.